# Compute exact integrals with quaternions

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, contour-integration, quaternions

It's common knowledge that complex analysis is helpful in computing a bunch of exact real integrals. Is there any occurence of quaternions/quaternion formalism helping in the same way? If not, what could be some plausible reasons?

---

**Motivation**

To address comments asking for motivation, I will try to outline some correspondences in quaternion analysis to complex analysis, especially those that in complex analysis are useful for evaluating definite real integrals.

Describing quaternions as $q= t+ix+jy+kz$, A. Sudberry's 1977 *Quaternionic Analysis* notes that if the Cauchy-Riemann analogue of $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+j\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+k\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=0$$
holds, then an analogue of Cauchy's theorem holds for $C$ a smooth, closed **3-manifold** in $\mathbb{H}$:

$$\int_{C} f(q) \; Dq=0, \\ \text{for }Dq = (dx \,dy\, dz-i\,dt\, dy \, dz - j\,dt\, dx \, dz - k\,dt \, dx \, dy).$$

He also notes that for such regular functions, an analogue of Cauchy's integral formula holds:

$$f(q_0) = \frac{1}{2 \pi^2} \int_{\partial D}\frac{1}{|q-q_0|^2} (q-q_0)^{-1} Dq \,f(q) $$

for $D$ a domain in which $f$ is regular.

These results for integrals at least partially mirror those in complex analysis. In complex analysis, Cauchy's theorem and integral formula are very useful for deriving the results of definite real integrals. The higher dimensionality of the quaternionic integrals maybe suggests that real integrals of functions of three variables would be useful to consider, but I do not know. Can these results for quaternionic integrals of regular functions be used to evaluate definite real integrals?

Comment: This is an interesting thought, but an instructive exercise would be to leave the burden of proof (in the legal, not mathematical, sense) to you. Why *would* there be methods of evaluating integrals with quaternions? The similarity of $i$, etc, is not enough (because at that point we could ask why not use group theory to calculate integrals, since complex numbers are a group, too, right?). Try editing your post with what you know about how complex numbers are used, and maybe articulate reasons or difficulty you might run into with quaternions.

Comment: Good luck getting a decent integration theory without commutativity.

Comment: @Randall What specifically did you have in mind with commutativity?  Not to say it doesn't make some things easier (like Fourier analysis) but I deal with integrals on non-commutative groups all the time.

Comment: @Kimball agreed, and I understand that, but to get integration over an entire division ring like $\mathbb{H}$ to distill down and respect integrals over $\mathbb{R}$ is a lot to ask.

Comment: Thank you all for your remarks. The remark of @Randall about commutativity is maybe the one that struck me the most, and made me realize how commutativity it is fundamental to obtain an obvious extension of real polynomials (and, then, analytical functions) to the complex plane.

Comment: Maybe some of you experts can write down an answer to the question of the OP ? It is an interesting one for non experts like me

Comment: @Randall Could you explain what you mean by "distill down and respect integrals over $\mathbb{R}$"?